# How to monitor a single page web app?

Tags: javascript, ajax, web-applications, google-analytics, monitoring

I wonder how one would monitor a single page web app so you can see what the user does in your app, what "pages" he visited etc.

Kinda like Google Analytics with statistics for a lot of things.

Answer (score 6):

Google Analytics is great for this. Check out custom events: http://code.google.com/apis/analytics/docs/tracking/eventTrackerGuide.html

It takes a fair amount more work than the "set it and forget it" type tracking you can do with traditional websites, but it's also pretty easy.

Comment: Yup. This is what we use at my job - where our product is a pretty massive single-page application. Granted, we've abstracted things a little further to make everything simpler to implement - but under the hood it's all Google Analytics custom events.

Comment: more recent tracking guide, if you use ga.js https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gajs/eventTrackerGuide

Comment: GA is not good. I have 10-15 users on my app all day long, and Google shows them connected for a few minutes only.

Answer (score 3):

It will not 'just work', you need to be calling trackPageView to make the requests count as pageviews and include all the visitor information that would be included (not trackEvent).  [This gist](https://gist.github.com/balupton/854622) is an old but popular solution to ajax navigation showing how to call trackPageView.  It is called right after the content from the new url is injected into the page, so an equivalent in a framework like Backbone.js would on view initialization, like [suggested in this guide](http://nerds.airbnb.com/how-to-add-google-analytics-page-tracking-to-57536).