# Monitoring angular.js single page app

Tags: javascript, django, angularjs

When I had a Django website, it was pretty easy to monitor the different part of my website (with **NewRelic** for example):

1. how much time it took to generate pages
2. time for query
3. etc...

But know I moved to a single page app using Angular.js framework, I must admit I don't know what I can monitor..

What if my clients have an issue with the app? I'll have no logs because it is client side.
How to know for all my users, the behavior of my application? (response time, query set performances...)

If you have good practices, I'm really interested in.

PS: I read [How to monitor a single page web app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9089575/how-to-monitor-a-single-page-web-app) but doesn't find it really useful. Specially for the logs part.

Answer (score 5):

Today's monitoring solutions are capable of delivering you specifically for Angular applications needed timings based on Real User Monitoring technology. Starts with timing the full initial page load as well as single XHR request timings your users trigger while click around on your page.

Beyond that for finding errors in the frontend code I know that Dynatrace allows you to also capture the JavaScript errors including stack trace which is pretty handy. You may want to check their [Angular Monitoring page](https://www.dynatrace.com/technologies/web/angular-monitoring/)

Answer (score 2):

Check out [Angulartics](http://luisfarzati.github.io/angulartics/), its an AngularJS project for integrating analytics.

Off the shelf it already integrates with 5 analytics providers, and you can extend it further. You can use it to monitor virtual pageviews and events. I'm not sure how it goes measuring page rendering time, but it would be a good place to start.